# Build Chrome extension using backbone.js? (Content Security Policy error when using template)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm building a project (like a website) with chrome extension, the js framework is backbone.js

The render view using template of backbone is very nice that help me easy to display data content. Everything work fine in normal project but not in chorme extension (it alway show the 'Content Security Policy' error message).

How can I deal with this problem? Or you can suggest me another framework that easy to build chrome extension.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Either change your copy of backbone.js to comply with applicable CSP, or [change the extension's CSP](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem.

I added:   "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"

to my manifest file and it work fine.

It's not recommended by Google Chrome but it's ok for me.

Thanks.